# Prove that $f(X_1,\cdots,X_k)\in \sigma (X_1,\cdots, X_k).$ (Measurable maps)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^k\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and $f\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_k$ random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{B})$.

Prove that $f(X_1,\cdot,X_k)\in \sigma (X_1,\cdots, X_k).$

I have not a clear Idea about how to proceed, next, some questions that I have.

The composition, $f\circ(X_1,\cdots,X_k): (\Omega,\mathcal{B}) \mapsto (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})),$ is correct?

$\sigma(X_1,\cdots,X_k)$ is a $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\Omega$?

Comment: do you mean $\sigma(f(X)) \subset \sigma(X)$?

Comment: Take $G \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and use measurability of $f$ together with the fact that $f(X_1, ..., X_k) \in G$ iff $(X_1, ..., X_k) \in f^{-1}(G)$ where $f^{-1}$ refers to the preimage.